# A new translation folder overrides my usual translation from "nowhere"

Tags: plugins, translation, directory

So I got to work on something really specific and strange on an old Wordpress I havn't edited already. The website is in French and English and this is a translation problem.

**To summaries the problem** :

1. The client warns me english version of the website is unavaible
2. There's a folder in `wp-content/languages` called `/themes` which contains an EN and FR .po and .mo
3. As long as this folder exists the whole english version of the website shows the french version
4. **I delete the folder from FTP and the PROBLEM IS SOLVED TEMPORARY**
5. The client calls me back few days later : the problem is back
6. I go to FTP and delete the folder
7. The clients calls me back few days later ....
8. And so on ...

I wish I could find WHAT or HOW this folder could be automatically generated, **the client ensures me he didn't even touch ONCE the backoffice**, so I don't really know what could go wrong.

I've looked into any option panel in the backoffice, and also checked a bit of code on the repo, but I can't find anything suspicious right now.

**Do you guys have an idea ?**

---

It seems they used back then a modified twentytwelve with some plugins here is the list ([x] means active / [ ] means not active / **bold** means I suspect it's the source of the problem):

- [ ] Akismet
- [x] CodeStyling Localization
- [x] Featured Images in RSS w/ Size and Position
- [x] FeedBurner Form
- [x] Google Sitemap by BestWebSoft
- [x] Google+ Author Information in Search Results (Free Version)
- [ ] GroupDocs Assembly Embedder
- [ ] Hello Dolly
- [ ] Integration: Yoast SEO & qTranslate-X
- [x] ManageWP - Worker
- [x] **qTranslate slug**
- [x] **qTranslate-X**
- [x] Regenerate Thumbnails
- [x] Simple History
- [ ] Yoast SEO

Comment: is it possible that the theme has an automatic update ? follow the version number of the theme to see if it changes.

Comment: thanks mmm for your help, how can I track this specific number ? I'm not aware of themes automatic update

Answer (score 0):

WordPress now auto–updates translations for extensions from official repositories.

This can be disabled by `add_filter( 'auto_update_translation', '__return_false' );`

I would note that if simply *presence* of translation files breaks functionality of the site — there are likely issues with how it was implemented in first place.